# angularfire2 Display Image after upload

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Using the example code from [Example Usage](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage).  I am able to upload an image file successfully and display the link to it. However, I would like to display the image in an img tag immediately after it is uploaded instead of a link to it. How would I accomplish this? I have tried something like this to no avail:

```
  profileUrl: Observable<string | null>;

  ....


  const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
  const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
  console.log('Image uploaded!');

  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL())
  )
  .subscribe();
```

And in my template file:

```
<img [src]="profileUrl | async" />
```

All of this is from the example, but I need to combine [Example Usage](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage) with the [Download Files](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#downloading-files) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can't subscribe to the snapshot, but you can to the download reference.

```
  const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
  const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
  console.log('Image uploaded!');
  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL()
      this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => (this.image = url));
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Hey, I replied to my first answer before seeing you figured this out.

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this recently. My task was to upload an image and then make that image appear on the same page used to upload the image. I wrote the WebAPI on the 'upload' server and this example doesn't use angular2fire so in your angular2fire subscribe response you will update the bound variable to the [src].

HTML:

```
<img *ngIf="uploaded" [src]="myURL">
```

TS:

```
uploadedImage = "savedNameOfUploadedFile.png";
uploaded = false;
myURL = '';
uploadImage(){
    this._httpClient.post(this.apiEndPoint + '/imageupload', formdata)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.uploaded = true;
            this.myURL = 'http://locationOfFileServer/' + this.uploadedImage;
          },
        error => { console.log(error); }
    );
}
```

My code was a lot more complex but this is a stripped down version for readability. I used a BehaviorSubject to communicate with my upload service and my view component, but like I said this is a stripped down version for readability. If you need more detail let me know and I'll copy/paste my production code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but this doesn't really help me modify my code, which does use angular2fire, to get it to work. You just posted completely different code which can accomplish something similar.

Comment: 1. Prior to posting the image file to the upload server save the image name with extsion in a variable, in my example I declared a variable of "uploadedImage" to store the image name. 2. in the subscribe response make the image viewable setting the html *ngIf=uploaded to true. 3. set the image src in the subscribe response event (you know the URL of the file server so concat the name saved in step 1 and use it as the image src URL). 4. Angular change detection will update the img tag to viewable and use the URL you set in step 3 as the image src. 5. This will work in any angular environment.